# Run time Pig Script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I would like to know how to write a Pig Latin script which has to be dynamic.

For example, I would like to get a list of students and pass every student name to the `FILTER` command.

Like below:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE STUDENT_NAME;

C = FILTER B BY STUDENT_NAME matches RESULT_OF_B;
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking... Could you try to give more detail about what you are trying to achieve? Because by the looks of what you have said, all you need is a join...

Comment: So, 'RESULT_OF_B' has to be dynamic in the script ?

Comment: Yes Sras. 
You are correct...

Comment: But what kind of data do you have in `RESULT_OF_B`? Is it a relation? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes Balduz. 
It would be a relation.

Comment: When you dump the B, you will get some Student names right.
I want to pass that student names to the schema c to filter.

Comment: Then what you want is a `JOIN`. Use `X = JOIN A BY (STUDENT_NAME), SECOND_RELATION BY (STUDENT_NAME)`. That way you will get only the records in SECOND_RELATION whose student name matches the ones in `B`.

Comment: ok.
Thank You So Much Balduz.